# Oracle ADF: Open Page from pressing a key on a InputText

Tags: oracle, jsf, oracle-adf

I have an InputText and I would like to be able to open a page when I have an InputText selected and I press for example key: F9.

So far I have a javascript that listens for a keyPress and that is working. And also I can show a Popup, but now I would like to transit to another page when the key is pressed:

Next I had the code:

```
function handleKeyEvent(evt) {
    var _keyCode = evt.getKeyCode();
    if (_keyCode == AdfKeyStroke.F9_KEY){
        //Do Something ...
          showPopup(evt)
      evt.cancel();
    }
}


function showPopup(event) 
{
    event.cancel();
    var source = event.getSource();
    var popupId = "p1";
    var popup = AdfPage.PAGE.findComponentByAbsoluteId(popupId);


if (!popup.isPopupVisible())
{   
  var hints = {};
  hints[AdfRichPopup.HINT_LAUNCH_ID] = source.getClientId();
  hints[AdfRichPopup.HINT_ALIGN_ID] = source.getClientId(); 
  hints[AdfRichPopup.HINT_ALIGN] = AdfRichPopup.ALIGN_AFTER_START;

  popup.show(hints);
}
}
```

How can this be done?

Thanks
Best Regards

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: added more information to the question

Answer (score 0):

You can change the location.href inside the handleEventKey function like this

```
function handleKeyEvent(evt) {
evt.cancel();
var _keyCode = evt.getKeyCode();
if (_keyCode == AdfKeyStroke.F9_KEY){
    //Change the page
   document.location.href = newUrl;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is a how do you want to navigate to this page, whats your surrounding?

If you simply need to open some external URL, then you can use solution provided by Amr (location.href).

However when you need to navigate to another view inside the task flow or another page inside your application or perform some action. You'll need to use action event queues.

To get to the backing bean from javascript you have to use `serverListener` component.
Then you can route message to your listener from javascript like this:

Sample with additional param `param1` passing and serverListener attached to component with id `cmp1`. (Don't forget to add `clientComponent=true` option to this component.

```
var evenSource = AdfPage.PAGE.findComponent("cmp1");
var paramValue = "parameter value";
AdfCustomEvent.queue(eventSource, "uploadProgress", {param1: paramValue1}, true);
```

This way you will route your event to the server and then you can do whatever you want in term of navigation from your bean.

You can get more details [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/apirefs.1111/e12419/tagdoc/af_serverListener.html).
Also [this sample](http://tompeez.wordpress.com/tag/afserverlistener/) may be useful.